# Бесконечная анимация animatedvectordrawable

Tags: android, android-animation, animate

Сделал анимацию следующим образом

```
<animated-vector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
<aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
    <vector
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24"
        android:viewportHeight="24"
        android:alpha="1">
        <path
            android:name="path"
            android:pathData="M 12.5 12 L 12 11.5 L 12 11.5 L 12.01 11.5 L 11.5 12 L 11.5 12 L 11.5 12 L 12 12.5 L 12 12.5 L 12 12.5 L 12.5 12 L 12.5 12 L 12.5 12 Z"
            android:fillColor="#000000"/>
    </vector>
</aapt:attr>
<target android:name="path">
    <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
        <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:ordering="sequentially">
            <objectAnimator
                android:name="path"
                android:propertyName="pathData"
                android:startOffset="200"
                android:duration="100"
                android:valueFrom="M 12.5 12 L 12 11.5 L 12 11.5 L 12.01 11.5 L 11.5 12 L 11.5 12 L 11.5 12 L 12 12.5 L 12 12.5 L 12 12.5 L 12.5 12 L 12.5 12 L 12.5 12 Z"
                android:valueTo="M 13.4 11.99 L 12.01 10.59 L 12 10.59 L 12.02 10.6 L 10.59 12 L 10.59 12 L 10.59 12 L 11.99 13.41 L 12 13.41 L 12 13.4 L 13.4 11.99 L 13.41 12 L 13.4 11.99 Z"
                android:valueType="pathType"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            <objectAnimator
                android:name="path"
                android:propertyName="pathData"
                android:startOffset="200"
                android:duration="100"
                android:valueFrom="M 13.4 11.99 L 12.01 10.59 L 12 10.59 L 12.02 10.6 L 10.59 12 L 10.59 12 L 10.59 12 L 11.99 13.41 L 12 13.41 L 12 13.4 L 13.4 11.99 L 13.41 12 L 13.4 11.99 Z"
                android:valueTo="M 13.4 11.99 L 12.01 10.59 L 12 10.59 L 12.02 10.6 L 10.59 12 L 10.59 12 L 10.59 12 L 11.99 13.41 L 12 13.41 L 17.59 19 L 19 17.59 L 13.41 12 L 13.4 11.99 Z"
                android:valueType="pathType"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            <objectAnimator
                android:name="path"
                android:propertyName="pathData"
                android:startOffset="200"
                android:duration="100"
                android:valueFrom="M 13.4 11.99 L 12.01 10.59 L 12 10.59 L 12.02 10.6 L 10.59 12 L 10.59 12 L 10.59 12 L 11.99 13.41 L 12 13.41 L 17.59 19 L 19 17.59 L 13.41 12 L 13.4 11.99 Z"
                android:valueTo="M 13.4 11.99 L 12.01 10.59 L 12 10.59 L 12.02 10.6 L 10.59 12 L 10.59 12 L 5 17.59 L 6.41 19 L 12 13.41 L 17.59 19 L 19 17.59 L 13.41 12 L 13.4 11.99 Z"
                android:valueType="pathType"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            <objectAnimator
                android:name="path"
                android:propertyName="pathData"
                android:startOffset="200"
                android:duration="100"
                android:valueFrom="M 13.4 11.99 L 12.01 10.59 L 12 10.59 L 12.02 10.6 L 10.59 12 L 10.59 12 L 5 17.59 L 6.41 19 L 12 13.41 L 17.59 19 L 19 17.59 L 13.41 12 L 13.4 11.99 Z"
                android:valueTo="M 13.4 11.99 L 12.01 10.59 L 12 10.59 L 6.41 5 L 5 6.41 L 10.59 12 L 5 17.59 L 6.41 19 L 12 13.41 L 17.59 19 L 19 17.59 L 13.41 12 L 13.4 11.99 Z"
                android:valueType="pathType"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            <objectAnimator
                android:name="path"
                android:propertyName="pathData"
                android:duration="100"
                android:valueFrom="M 13.4 11.99 L 12.01 10.59 L 12 10.59 L 6.41 5 L 5 6.41 L 10.59 12 L 5 17.59 L 6.41 19 L 12 13.41 L 17.59 19 L 19 17.59 L 13.41 12 L 13.4 11.99 Z"
                android:valueTo="M 19 6.41 L 17.59 4.99 L 12 10.59 L 6.41 5 L 5 6.41 L 10.59 12 L 5 17.59 L 6.41 19 L 12 13.41 L 17.59 19 L 19 17.59 L 13.41 12 L 19 6.41 Z"
                android:valueType="pathType"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            <objectAnimator
                android:name="path"
                android:propertyName="pathData"
                android:duration="100"
                android:valueFrom="M 19 6.41 L 17.59 4.99 L 12 10.59 L 6.41 5 L 5 6.41 L 10.59 12 L 5 17.59 L 6.41 19 L 12 13.41 L 17.59 19 L 19 17.59 L 13.41 12 L 19 6.41 Z"
                android:valueTo="M 19 6.41 L 17.59 4.99 L 12 10.59 L 6.41 5 L 5 6.41 L 10.59 12 L 5 17.59 L 6.41 19 L 12 13.41 L 17.59 19 L 19 17.59 L 13.41 12 L 19 6.41 Z"
                android:valueType="pathType"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            <objectAnimator
                android:name="path"
                android:propertyName="pathData"
                android:duration="100"
                android:valueFrom="M 19 6.41 L 17.59 4.99 L 12 10.59 L 6.41 5 L 5 6.41 L 10.59 12 L 5 17.59 L 6.41 19 L 12 13.41 L 17.59 19 L 19 17.59 L 13.41 12 L 19 6.41 Z"
                android:valueTo="M 17 13.01 L 17 11.01 L 13 11 L 13.01 7 L 11.01 7 L 11 11 L 7 10.99 L 7 12.98 L 11 12.99 L 10.99 17 L 12.98 17 L 12.99 13 L 17 13.01 Z"
                android:valueType="pathType"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            <objectAnimator
                android:name="path"
                android:propertyName="pathData"
                android:duration="100"
                android:valueFrom="M 17 13.01 L 17 11.01 L 13 11 L 13.01 7 L 11.01 7 L 11 11 L 7 10.99 L 7 12.98 L 11 12.99 L 10.99 17 L 12.98 17 L 12.99 13 L 17 13.01 Z"
                android:valueTo="M 13.41 14.84 L 14.82 13.42 L 13.41 12 L 14.84 10.59 L 13.42 9.18 L 12 10.59 L 10.59 9.17 L 9.19 10.57 L 10.59 11.99 L 9.17 13.41 L 10.57 14.81 L 11.99 13.41 L 13.41 14.84 Z"
                android:valueType="pathType"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            <objectAnimator
                android:name="path"
                android:propertyName="pathData"
                android:duration="100"
                android:valueFrom="M 13.41 14.84 L 14.82 13.42 L 13.41 12 L 14.84 10.59 L 13.42 9.18 L 12 10.59 L 10.59 9.17 L 9.19 10.57 L 10.59 11.99 L 9.17 13.41 L 10.57 14.81 L 11.99 13.41 L 13.41 14.84 Z"
                android:valueTo="M 10.98 13 L 12.99 13 L 13 13 L 13 13.02 L 13 11.02 L 13.01 11 L 13.02 11 L 11.04 11 L 11.02 10.99 L 11 10.98 L 11 12.96 L 11 12.98 L 10.98 13Z"
                android:valueType="pathType"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
            <objectAnimator
                android:name="path"
                android:propertyName="pathData"
                android:duration="100"
                android:valueFrom="M 10.98 13 L 12.99 13 L 13 13 L 13 13.02 L 13 11.02 L 13.01 11 L 13.02 11 L 11.04 11 L 11.02 10.99 L 11 10.98 L 11 12.96 L 11 12.98 L 10.98 13Z"
                android:valueTo="M 12.5 12 L 12 11.5 L 12 11.5 L 12.01 11.5 L 11.5 12 L 11.5 12 L 11.5 12 L 12 12.5 L 12 12.5 L 12 12.5 L 12.5 12 L 12.5 12 L 12.5 12 Z"
                android:valueType="pathType"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
                />
        </set>
    </aapt:attr>
</target>
```

Запускаю ее в активности

```
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.avd_vector_anim_cancel);
        AnimatedVectorDrawable avd;
        Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
        avd = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) drawable;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            avd.start();
        }
```

Как сделать так чтобы анимация постоянно повторялась? Сейчас она после первого прогона останавливается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поступил следующим образом и вроде как все работает

```
final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        Thread.sleep(1500);
                        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                            break;
                        imageView.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                                    avd.start();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        thread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

можно каждому `objectAnimator` добавить атрибут `android:repeatCount="infinite"`
Или в коде

```
avd.registerAnimationCallback(new Animatable2.AnimationCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable drawable) {
        super.onAnimationEnd(drawable);
        avd.start();
    }

});
avd.start();
```

Comment: если каждому objectAnimator-у добавить android:repeatCount="infinite" то перезапустится каждый objectAnimator.
registerAnimationCallback не дает никаких результатов